# Function with constant & static local variable, makes function reentrant?

Tags: c, variables, static, constants, reentrancy

I have a function with a local variable who is static & constant, does the function is reentrant?

This is the code:

```
void foo(unsigned char *pucBuffer,
         int            iBytes,
         unsigned int  *puiOUT)
{
   static const long rg_uliLUT[4] = {0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c,
                                     0x990951ba};
   while(iBytes--)
   {
     *puiOUT = (*puiOUT >> 8) ^ rg_uliLUT[(*puiOUT & 0x03) ^ *pucBuffer++];
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: No. This is because const does not force immutability.

Comment: @Manoj: Surely `const` does enforce immutability?! There are "hacks" to get around it (e.g. take address of and cast to non-const pointer), but assuming no funny business, a const variable cannot be changed by the program.

Comment: @Jimbo - I meant the same.

Comment: @Manoj: Okay, so you were talking about the "hack"?

Comment: @ManojAwasthi Modifying a variable declared with const and without volatile is undefined behavior, making the object immutable for all sensible definitions of the word.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `rg_uliLUT` is `const` then yes, I think your function is re-entrant. If that variable were not `const` and was modified then the answer would be no, but because it is constant, no caller will be able to modify another caller's state variables (anything that can be changed is on the caller's private stack and the only "shared" data cannot be changed).

From good old [***wikipedia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_function)

> In computing, a computer program or subroutine is called reentrant if
>   it can be interrupted in the middle of its execution and then safely
>   called again ("re-entered") before its previous invocation's complete
>   execution.

All the function state is private to each caller (on caller stack). The only other state is constant, so because the caller can't modify it, to any other caller it will always look the same, so won't change function behavior if two threads, for example, are in the function at the same time.

PS: It is not re-entrant if the memory pointed to by `puiOUT` is shared between callers. Also seems like `pucBuffer` could be `char const *` because it is not written to.